# How to load different mail_driver config setting based on app_env setting in Laravel 5.3 App>

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5.3

In my PHP Laravel 5.3 app I have my config settings in my `.env` file with the 
`APP_ENV=local` which can be changed to `APP_ENV=production` when my app is in production/live mode.

In that `.env` file I also have a `MAIL_DRIVER=preview` setting which gets pulled into my `config/mail.php` config file with `env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp')` like this:

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
]
```

So now my question is, when I change my `.env` setting `APP_ENV=local` into `APP_ENV=production`

How can I make it load a different `env('MAIL_DRIVER')` setting based on that `env('APP_ENV')` setting?

is there a way to load different `.env` files for each environment or different config files or how do you handle this in Laravel 5.3.

I remember in older versions of Laravel you simply created a new folder in the config folder for each environment but the whole config system is different from those older versions.

Comment: Why do you set your ```MAIL_DRIVER``` to ```preview```? Just change the ```MAIL_DRIVER``` value to the driver you want in the ```.env``` file of your local and production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Laravel 5, you have a different copy of your `.env` file in each environment.

This file is NOT committed into your repository. Rather, your `.env.example` file is, and that is what you make a copy of and name as `.env` in the environment.

In previous versions of Laravel (i.e. <= 4) you could have separate environment files in the same checked out copy of the project and switch between environments, but that doesn't actually make much sense.

Keep your `.env.example` file up to date with all the options you will need in your app, and initialize them to empty values. When you deploy to a new environment, you copy it as a new file, which keeps you from accidentally committing credentials to your repo and keeps things simple:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Then edit the file and set the values to be appropriate in that specific environment. For example, instead of using test API keys, you may use the production keys for some service. Editing, for example:

```
sudo vim .env # If you like VIM
```

or

```
sudo nano .env # If you like NANO
```

An exception to what I just said above is with testing. [Per the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration):

> You may also create a .env.testing file. This file will override values from the .env file when running PHPUnit tests or executing Artisan commands with the --env=testing option.

In that case though, having your .env.testing file in your repo is most likely acceptable assuming it doesn't contain any sensitive production values, which it probably shouldn't anyway.

Comment: I see what you mean.  So I might make a `.env.local` and `.env.production` files and have a simple function that can run  `cp .env.local .env` so that I can store different settings and on environment change have it copy that env file to the main `.env` file.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `.env.local` and `.env.production` anymore. Those should be compressed into a single `.env.example` file, which you then make a copy of and fill in the values. What would you have in your production environment that you would NOT want in development/staging/testing other than the specific values of the configuration such as keys/passwords/etc.?